# Update SQL column, based on complex conditions from other columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, compare

I need help with figuring out how to update values in a SQL Server column, based on two additional criteria and enclose the while in a "foreach" (I know there is no foreach in T-SQL) loop. I managed to get SQL view, containing all the params involved:

[SQL View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Efx.png)

Sorry, was not able to get the table to display properly.

[Here you can find a an example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5352000a-1f8f-424f-aaec-2b349cc642cc/tsql-foreach-in-foreach-or-how-to-achieve-this?forum=transactsql)

What I need in this particular case is to find `SamAccountNames`, which are members of more then one group (same `SamAccountName`, having different GroupIDs), compare the `GroupStartDate` for this SAM and get the earliest date.

This date I will then use in a stored procedure to update each job of the specified users (SAM).

In this particular example: TonyS is member of two groups (78 and 79), so he is eligible for a check. When I check the GroupStartDate I see that Tony can have a job, starting earliest 2017-03-06 (Job with UniqueID1), so in this case I need to update Tony's other jobs with this date (Job UniqueID2 need to be updated).

I have searched and tried many different things, but so far I couldn't get even close to what has to be done.

Any hits are greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Tony

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stackoverflow. For any specific problem you are having please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad.

Comment: Hi Igor,may I reference a thread I have opened in the MS Technet Forum, where I have given a particular example? It is very hard to format the tables here in a proper way...

Comment: paste table results to: https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/, hit `create table` button, copy generated table, paste into answer, format as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is group the records by `SamAccountName` and get the minimum `GroupStartDate`, which will be the "earliest" job starting day.

```
-- get the ones with more than one groupId
;with multiple_groups_cte as
(
    select j.SamAccountName, count(distinct GroupId) nr_groups, MIN(groupstartdate) Earliest_GroupStartDate
    from #jobs j
    group by SamAccountName
    having count(distinct GroupId) > 1
)
select  SamAccountName, Earliest_GroupStartDate
from multiple_groups_cte
```

This query would give you the following result:

```
SamAccountName  Earliest_GroupStartDate

GarryT          2017-01-08 00:00:00.0000000
TonyS           2017-03-06 00:00:00.0000000
```

Comment: Hey, almost there..Thanks for your input. The only thing that needs to be considered also is that GarryT's jobs are actually within the same group (GroupID 81). I need to check only Tony's jobs as he is the only one, having membership in two different groups. Any suggestions how to edit your example? Big thanks!

Comment: The query is still the same. In my case, I inserted in my temp table that I used to re-create your problem two records for GarryT, with GroupIDs 81 and 82. If you have just 81 as a GroupId for GarryT as well, it should work.

Notice the count of groups is *distinct*. Give it a try! :)

Comment: Hey, I would need a bit more time to test. I won't forget your input and will return to give you feedback and mark this accordingly. Thnaks once again.

Comment: So, my friend, you need 5 Min to solve something that I coldn't solve for two consecutive day. I really, really appreciate it. How can I mark the question as solved, so that you get the points?

Comment: Haha so nice that I could help! I guess you just need to mark the answer as correct, something like that.
 Happy t-sql-ing :)!